# In Oracle SQL, how can I quickly find out the number of rows and columns in a list of tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

To prepare the migration of a database from Oracle to another provider, I must find out the number of rows and columns in lots of tables.

Is there a procedure, query, etc. that would take the list of tables as input and output a table with attributes `name of table`, `number of rows` and `number of columns` ?

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of rows in a table you'll have to use the `COUNT` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SOME_OWNER.SOME_TABLE
```

To find the number of columns you can use the DBA_TAB_COLS view:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM DBA_TAB_COLS
  WHERE OWNER = 'SOME_OWNER' AND
        TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know how to do that, I was hoping to find something a little bit more automatic :)